# How to do recursion parsing of Array of Multi-Level Dicitonary

Tags: ios, objective-c

i have common values for nested dictionaries of array in JSON response.

I want to achieve it in level wise, so that all recursion is done inside loop.

Code- >

.h

```
@interface MyCategory : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *type;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *categoryId;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *catIconLeft;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *catIconRight;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *parentId;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray  *categories;

- (id)initWithRootDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary;
@end
```

.m------->

```
 @implementation
 - (id)initWithRootDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary
{
self = [super init];
self.type = dictionary[@"type"];
self.name = dictionary[@"name"];
self.categoryId = dictionary[@"categoryId"];
self.catIconLeft = dictionary[@"catIconLeft"];
self.catIconRight = dictionary[@"catIconRight"];
self.parentId = dictionary[@"parentId"];
if (dictionary[@"category"]) {
    NSMutableArray *categories = [NSMutableArray new];
    for (NSDictionary *cat in dictionary[@"category"]) {
        MyCategory *category = [[MyCategory alloc] initWithRootDictionary:cat];
        [categories addObject:category];
    }
    self.categories = categories;
 }

 return self;
 }
 @end
```

View Controller Call-->

```
-(void)call_CategoryListData
{ 
//...
NSMutableDictionary * responseDic = [results objectForKey:@"RESPONSE"];
NSMutableArray *      catArray    = [responseDic objectForKey:@"Category"];

NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray new];
for (NSDictionary *categoryDic in catArray) {
    MyCategory *category = [[MyCategory alloc] initWithRootDictionary:categoryDic];
    [result addObject:category];
}

}
```

The result array contains again dictionaries and arrays in nested level.
 I want to parse array of dict in such way all main category and sub category and child categories should belong to corresponding object.

For example

- Electronic 
           -> Mobile Accessories-->Headset, Charger, Battery etc.....
            ----------so on----------

My JSON [LINK](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11772059/)

Comment: please explain clear. What do you want?. BTW good question !

Comment: Sorry, but your question is bloody mess. Nothing is clear from your post, other than you wan't to parse JSON response using recursion

Comment: @LalitKumar please see updated quest

Comment: @SergiiMartynenkoJr  could u see updated one

Comment: Take a look at my answer bellow - this is what you need. Only thing - remove code from constructor, that checks for @"category" in dictionary - this is not the right place to do it. And you will not create products in such a manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to understand, what do you want, but I'll try to answer

Your recursion method will get some dictionary, create object described in it, and call itself with sub dictionary, if incoming dict is category

```
- (NSArray *) mapCategories:(NSArray*) categoriesDictArray {
    NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray array];
    for(NSDictionary *objectDict in categoriesDictArray) {
        MyCategory *category = [MyCategory categoryWithDictionary:objectDict];
        [result addObject:category];
        if(objectDict[@"Category"]) {
           category. categories = [self mapCategories:objectDict[@"Category"]];    
        }
    }

    return result;
}

//place, where you get your first call
NSArray *mappedCategories = [self mapCategories:result[@"RESPONSE"][@"Category"] ];
```

Hope you get the idea

Comment: i m confused in this should i call this in constructor on use mine

Comment: Nope, not in constructor. Use it in place, where you get you server response

Comment: this really i dont understand MyProduct . in my case it is MyCategory , could u modified it on answer please  - (MyProduct *) mapProduct:(NSDictionary*) productDict {
    MyProdcut *product = [MyProduct productWithDictionary:productDict];
    return product;
}

Comment: Just forget about MyProduct - take a look at updated answer

Comment: NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
it is not the right way i guess appropriate converion of array to mutable dict. please check i m ising it getting errors.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81615/discussion-between-imran-and-sergii-martynenko-jr).